# Reproducing errors that happen in production (Android)

Tags: android, google-play, production

Ok, I'm not really sure if I am asking the right question. I published an app to production and there are some reported errors that happened on various devices (HTC, LG, Huawei..). What is the best way to reproduce these errors on my device? Or do I have to have the aforementioned devices to test it? I can't release an update if I don't exactly know what the error is and why it happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do only **2** things :

1) `Contact the person through google plus who reports the issue and ask to tell the steps to reproduce the crash`

2) Or `Read the Stack trace of Crash on Google Developer Console and Test them on Devices.`

Like : Below is the Snap of the crash on my application on Moto G... I figured it Out with the help of Stack Trace.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I have the stack trace, but I often cannot reproduce the error even if I know what could be the problem. I never know if I really corrected it.

Comment: Hmmmm... Then try to catch every suspected Line of Code :)

Comment: I'll try.. thanks, I will mark your answer as a correct one, as it really is the only way :D